# find expression of stream line function $\psi (x, y)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

i have a question of partial derivatives here:

> given that the velocity components in two dimensional flow of a fluid, 
>   $$u=\frac{y^3}{3}+2x-x^2y \quad \text{&} \quad v=xy^2-2y-\frac{x^3}{3}$$
>   find out the stream line function $\psi(x, y)$

my trial:

for 2-D flow,  $\frac{\partial \psi}{dy}=-u$ & $\frac{\partial \psi}{dx}=v$, plugging the values of u & v
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{dy}=-\frac{y^3}{3}-2x+x^2y$$
integrating with respect to y, 
$$\psi=-\frac{y^4}{12}-2xy+\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+f(x) \ \ \ \ ..................\ \ (1)$$
differentiating $\psi$ with respect to x, 
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{dx}=-2y+xy^2+f'(x)$$
but $\frac{\partial \psi}{dx}=v=xy^2-2y-\frac{x^3}{3}$ now equating both, 
$$xy^2-2y-\frac{x^3}{3}=-2y+xy^2+f'(x)$$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{x^3}{3}$$
integrating with respect to x, $$f(x)=-\frac{x^4}{12}+C$$ 
C being constant of integration, plugging the value of f(x) in (1), stream line function 
$$\psi (x, y)=-\frac{y^4}{12}-2xy+\frac{x^2y^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}+C$$$$=\frac{x^2y^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{y^4}{12}-2xy+C$$
but, my book says the answer is $\psi(x, y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{y^4}{12}-2xy$, but i don't know the reason why constant of integration C is neglected.

somebody please help me explain or give me reasons. thank you

Comment: What is the convention of streamline function $\psi(x,y)$?
$$f(z)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)$$then $$u+iv=\partial_x \phi+i\partial_y \psi=\partial_y \psi-i\partial_y \psi$$ or $f(z)=\psi(x,y)+i\phi(x,y)$?

Comment: The constant $C$ is ignored because at the end you only care about the flow. If you set $C$ to a fixed number, it will not change the dynamics of the streamlines.